# how to change the background color of activity on button click where color is picked from radio button

Tags: java, android

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    View someView = findViewById(R.id.activity_success);
    View root = someView.getRootView();
    // what should be written here?? to display color
    txtA.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getResourceTypeName(???));
```

---

the application is like.

We have different radio button with colors as options and on click of `radioButton1` red color is displayed in multi line text area, and on clicking on <kbd>Apply to Background</kbd>, that color is applied to whole activity in background.

Now the question is what should be the code given in `getResource()` so that it picks the color from every `RadioButton` to apply it to the activity background.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? your question is unclear and your codes are insufficient to understand what you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change (getResources().getResourceTypeName(???) to (getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolorname);

Answer (score 0):

`getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolorname);`

is depricated from API 23, Use instead:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourcolorname);
```